# Keep on listen to udp port server python with recvfrom(), when processing data

Tags: python, sockets, server, udp

I have a simple server

```
while True:
    d = s.recvfrom(UDP_BUFFER_SIZE)
    process(d)
```

and a simple client:

```
while True:
    sock.sendto(data, addr):
```

But I found out that during processing the server is not listening any more, and I loose data that do received. I know UDP can loose data, but here the UDP implementation and the processing that might take too long, preventing me from collecting data.

How is it possible to process the received data and still listen to the port ?
Even exporting the recvfrom() to a thread, will likely have some time between listening:

```
while True:
    d = s.recvfrom(UDP_BUFFER_SIZE)
    export_data(d) # make it faster, but export time can still miss packets.
```

Comment: You *are* listening, unless you closed the socket, which you aren't. You do realize that UDP is an unreliable protocol?

Comment: I am using udp for process communications. those 2 process are on the same PC, and still missing inforamtion. it seems that the cause is the processing time, I will try debug again.